# Photos not shown in all Google+ Communities when shared

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

Sometimes I share same photo with same text, and link, to different communities and when I check some of those communities with private browsing my photos are not shown.

I have noticed this since few photos would yield a high number of +1 and some others no +1 at all.

Is there some sort of spam algorithm that is incorrectly flagging me? If that's the case, any idea on how not to be flagged?